# Is the following question pertinent to chess, and hence a good one to ask on boardgames stack exchange?

Tags: discussion, chess

My questions are: Has anyone ever played a variant of chess such that in the starting position Bishops and Knights are switched?  (So White's back row looks like this: RBNQKNBR)  How can I find notes on this variant?

I've just asked a chess question that was not strictly about chess, and while it was accepted as a good enough question, I was referred to the meta site for analyzing any further dubious questions.  If it doesn't fit in at boardgames, where should I ask it?

Thanks!

Comment: I think the knight's tour question would have been a reasonable fit for the maths stack exchange site too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think variant questions are fine, as long as they're normally good questions to ask.

Having said that, I don't thnk "Has anyone ever played X" questions are good questions.

You might try something more like "Is there a known chess variant that ...".

Comment: Thank you!  I've been wondering many things about chess, for years, and just now came across stack exchange.  I must say I am very impressed!  It's a sure recipe for happy users!

Comment: How's this: Is there a variant of chess such that in the starting position Bishops and Knights are switched?  Where can I learn more about this variant?  -  I know it's two questions, but the second can be inside, and the first can be the title.

Comment: That'd probably be ok.